# Is it safe to send the unencoded JSON output?

Tags: security, 8

The mobile app developers wants an api to get a list of articles from our Drupal site.
It should have these fields in the output:

1. nid
2. title
3. field_teaser_body

The api resonse has to be in JSON format.

The field type of `field_teaser_body` field is `Long text` and text processing is `Plain text`.

I created a custom code to get this working. Here's a simplified version of it.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
  ->condition('n.status', 1)
  ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')

$result = $query->execute();

$nodes = array();
foreach ($result as $value) {
  $node = node_load($value->nid);

  $data = array(
    'nid' => $node->nid,
    'title' => $node->title,
    'field_teaser_body' => !empty($node->field_teaser_body['und'][0]['value']) ? check_plain($node->field_teaser_body['und'][0]['value']) : '',
  );

  $data = (object) $data;
  array_push($nodes, $data);
}

$content = new stdClass();
$content->nodes = $nodes;

print json_encode($content);
```

Just for the security purpose, I'm using `check_plain()` function to sanitize the teaser body text. But, when using this function, it encodes all special characters.

For e.g.,
`Bob's height is > than Alice.`
converts to
`Bob&#039;s height is &gt; than Alice.`

The mobile app developers said that they don't want any encoded text in the JSON output.

**Is it a safe practice to send the unencoded (unsanitized) text in the JSON output ?**

Comment: Just a note, but perhaps better to use `drupal_json_encode` than `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to encode or escape anything yourself. json_encode() will take care of properly escaping any special purpose characters.

Answer (score 0):

From a Drupal standpoint, it's ok to send markup in JSON fields.

After all, you're delivering the content which may need markup to work (e.g. `<p>` & `<h1>` tags for formatting). The onus should be on the app developer consuming the JSON to do sanitary checks (e.g. `<script>` injection, broken markup, malicious `<iframe>`, etc.). If you have any custom input forms that's where you should be doing your sanitary checks.

With all that said, if security is a concern, I'd suggest looking at a ready made solution for delivering content in a JSON format (e.g. [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)). Any community-provided module solution is likely to have more security vetting than your own solution.